# System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send success on local host but failed on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

the code work successfully on local host but it's failed when I deploy it on the server the error always:
The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.

I read many of issues about this case but until now I did not solve my issue:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

protected void Submit_Buttom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("emailadress@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("emailadress@gmail.com"));
        mailMessage.Subject = "New Student";

        if (File_upload1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpFileCollection hfc1 = Request.Files;

            // LOOP THROUGH EACH SELECTED FILE.
            for (int i = 0; i <= hfc1.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc1[i];

                // CREATE A FILE ATTACHMENT.
                Attachment objAttachements = new Attachment(hpf.InputStream,hpf.FileName);

                // ADD FILE ATTACHMENT TO THE EMAIL.
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(objAttachements);
            }
        }

        mailMessage.Body ="<div>......</div>" + File_Grade1.File_upload1 + "<div>....</div>";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("emailaddress@gmail.com", "password");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);

        Label1.Text = "Success";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `addresses` parameter ?

Comment: Would you please format that code a little?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'addresses' cannot be an empty string.
Parameter name: addresses

Comment: @PhilippeB. this error show when I submit a button notice that the code work fine on local host

Comment: Yes but what is `addresses` ? Your problem comes from here, if you don't know what it is, you wont solve your problem.